# Getting Checkboxes to work on Frontend Forms

Tags: frontend, checkboxes

I have tried to follow the instructions listed [here for checkboxes on frontend forms](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/checkboxes-fields) but have not been successful in implementation.

First, here is my code:

```
<form method="post" action="" accept-charset="UTF-8" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class="form-group">
<h3>Push to GistServers for Gist {{ entry.id }}</h3>
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="gistClient/pushGistUnits">
<input type="hidden" name="entryId" value="{{ entry.id }}">
<p>Select Gist Categories for Distribution.</p>
{% if entry.gistCategories | length == 0 %}
    <ul>
        {% for option in entry.gistCategories.options %}
        <input type="checkbox" value="{{ option.value }}" name="fields[gistCategories][]"> {{ option.label }}<br>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}    
    <ul>
    {% for checkboxOption in entry.gistCategories %}
        {% set checked = false %}

        {% if checkboxOption.selected %}
            {% set checked = true %}

        {% endif %}

        {% if not checked %}
            <input type="checkbox" value="{{ checkboxOption.value }}" name="fields[gistCategories][]" {% if checked %} checked="checked"{% endif %}>{{ checkboxOption.label }}<br>
        {% endif %}

        <input type="checkbox" value="{{ checkboxOption.value }}" name="fields[gistCategories][]" {% if checked %} checked="checked"{% endif %}>{{ checkboxOption.label }}<br>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{%endif%}

{{ getCsrfInput() }}
{% if entry.socialPush == true %}
    {% set socialPush = "Push to GistServers"%}
    {% set socialPushBtn = "default"%}
{% else %}
    {% set socialPush = "Push to GistServers"%}
    {% set socialPushBtn = "success"%}
{% endif %}

<button class="btn btn-{{socialPushBtn}}  btn-sm btn " style="margin:10px 15px 0 0;" type="submit" name="fields[gistDraft]" value="0">{{ socialPush }}</button>
</div>
```

Now for screen caps showing behavior.

Before form submit

[image]

CP View after form submit

[image]

Frontend form after submit.

[image]

Ideally, After I submit the frontend form my users would be able to see all checkboxes again in case they need to change the selections. I am at a loss and would appreciate some rescue here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first loop you're using loops over `entry.gistCategories.options`, which contains all the options available. However, in the second loop (when `entry.gistCategories|length !== 0`), you're only looping over the options that have been selected.

Try this:

```
{% if entry.gistCategories | length == 0 %}
    <ul>
        {% for option in entry.gistCategories.options %}
            {# output checkboxes #}
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}  
    <ul>
        {% for checkboxOption in entry.gistCategories.options %}
            {# output checkboxes #}
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since the form was already submitted, your code is only looping through the checkboxes that were checked.

Just add `.options` to your second `for` block like you have above:

```
{% for checkboxOption in entry.gistCategories.options %}
```

That'll loop through all of 'em, checked or not.